# My PHP mail form shows up empty, no id info

Tags: php, forms, email

my php mail form comes up empty in my mailbox, for some reason it doesn't gather the textfield information typed in in the HTML.

This is how it shows up in my mailbox:

```
Email: 
First Name: 
Last Name: 
Phone: 
Vehicle:
Engine: 
Tickbox Engine: 
Tickbox Aerodynamics: 
Tickbox Wheels: 
Tickbox Suspension: 
Tickbox Exhaust: 
Tickbox Brakes: 
Tickbox Interior: 
Message:
```

This is my php code:

```
    $firtnameField = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastnameField = $_POST['lastname'];
    $phonenameField = $_POST['phone'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];  
    $vehicleField = $_POST['vehicle'];  
    $engineField = $_POST['engine'];
    $tickboxengineField = $_POST['infoengine']; 
    $tickboxaerodynamicsField = $_POST['infoaero']; 
    $tickboxwheelsField = $_POST['infowheels']; 
    $tickboxsuspensionField = $_POST['infosuspension']; 
    $tickboexhaustField = $_POST['infoexhaust'];    
    $tickboxbrakesField = $_POST['infobrakes']; 
    $tickboxinteriorField = $_POST['infointerior']; 
    $tickboxmessageField = $_POST['message'];   
    $tickboxsendField = $_POST['infosend']; 

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $email <br>
First Name: $firstname <br>
Last Name: $lastname <br>
Phone: $phone <br>
Vehicle: $vehicle <br>
Engine: $engine <br>
Tickbox Engine: $infoengine <br>
Tickbox Aerodynamics: $infoaero <br>
Tickbox Wheels: $infowheels <br>
Tickbox Suspension: $infosuspension <br>
Tickbox Exhaust: $infoexhaust <br>
Tickbox Brakes: $infobrakes <br>
Tickbox Interior: $infointerior <br>
Message: $message <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $succes = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

And this is my HTML:

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="requestform.php">
      <table width="540" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">First Name</td>
          <td width="4%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Last Name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="48%"><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="45" /></td>
          <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%"><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Phone</td>
          <td width="4%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Email</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="48%"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="45" /></td>
          <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Vehicle &amp; Model</td>
          <td width="4%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Engine</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="48%"><input name="vehicle" type="text" id="vehicle" size="45" /></td>
          <td width="4%">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%"><input name="engine" type="text" id="engine" size="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Please select</td>
          <td width="4%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infoengine" id="infoengine" />
Engine Technology</td>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infoaero" id="infoaero" />
                Aerodynamics</td>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infowheels" id="infowheels" />
Sport Wheels</td>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infosuspension" id="infosuspension" />
                Suspension</td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infoexhaust" id="infoexhaust" />
Exhaust Technology</td>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infobrakes" id="infobrakes" />Brake Technology</td>
              <td height="25"><input type="checkbox" name="infointerior" id="infointerior" />
                Interior</td>
              <td height="25">&nbsp;</td>
              </tr>
          </table></td>
          </tr>
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td width="48%" height="30" class="subheadline">Message</td>
          <td width="4%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><textarea name="message" id="message" cols="74" rows="5">Please send me information…</textarea></td>
          </tr>
        <tr valign="bottom">
          <td width="48%" height="30">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="4%" height="30" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="48%" height="30" align="right"><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Request Information" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

I am sure you can see I am far away of being a pro, it's my first PHP mail form I am trying out. Watched a tutorial and tried to convert it to my needs… Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 3):

You lost the `Field` suffix from each of the second variable names which you use to print. e.g. it's `$firtnameField` then it becomes `$firstname`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the original name in `$body`

```
$firtnameField = $_POST['firstname'];
....
```

You are forgetting `Field` suffix in variables

```
$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $emailField <br>
First Name: $firstnameField <br>
Last Name: $lastnameField <br>
Phone: $phoneField <br>
....
```

Answer (score -1):

bro use this php code 
that will work add it on php page

```
$webmaster = 'yoour_email@mail.com';
$emailSubject = 'Your Subjject here';

    $firtnameField = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastnameField = $_POST['lastname'];
    $phonenameField = $_POST['phone'];
    $emailField = $_POST['email'];  
    $vehicleField = $_POST['vehicle'];  
    $engineField = $_POST['engine'];
    $tickboxengineField = $_POST['infoengine']; 
    $tickboxaerodynamicsField = $_POST['infoaero']; 
    $tickboxwheelsField = $_POST['infowheels']; 
    $tickboxsuspensionField = $_POST['infosuspension']; 
    $tickboexhaustField = $_POST['infoexhaust'];    
    $tickboxbrakesField = $_POST['infobrakes']; 
    $tickboxinteriorField = $_POST['infointerior']; 
    $tickboxmessageField = $_POST['message'];   
    $tickboxsendField = $_POST['infosend']; 

    $body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Email: $emailField <br>
First Name: $firtnameField <br>
Last Name: $lastnameField <br>
Phone: $phonenameField <br>
Vehicle: $vehicleField <br>
Engine: $engineField <br>
Tickbox Engine: $tickboxengineField <br>
Tickbox Aerodynamics: $tickboxaerodynamicsField <br>
Tickbox Wheels: $tickboxwheelsField <br>
Tickbox Suspension: $tickboxsuspensionField <br>
Tickbox Exhaust: $tickboexhaustField <br>
Tickbox Brakes: $infobrakes <br>
Tickbox Interior: $tickboxinteriorField <br>
Message: $tickboxmessageField <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: Alpha RooT <$email>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $succes = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: The point of an answer is not "Here, I fixed it!", moreso "It didn't work because...". Also, consider losing the bro.